# Python - Creating a timer that activate a pin on the arduino a specified time

Tags: python, timer, arduino

i'm trying to create a timer that will control lighting fixture through arduino, shift register and relays.

I got a checkbox, when checked it check the time and compare it to a variable, and activate/deactivate the proper pin on the arduino.

But when already checked, the function wont see if the current time goes over the threshold.

```
    def setCheckButtonText1():
        if varCheckButton1.get():
            varLabel.set("Lumiere du Jour Activer")
            global timetimer
            time3 = time.strftime('%H%M')
            if time3 != timetimer:
                timetimer = time3
            hrlever = '2101'
            if time3 >= hrlever:
                varLabel.set("Led On")
                ser.write(bytes('H', 'UTF-8'))
            else:
                varLabel.set("LED OFF")
                ser.write(bytes('L', 'UTF-8'))
        else:
            varLabel.set("LED OFF")
            ser.write(bytes('L', 'UTF-8'))
```

I'm really green at this so every advice is more than welcome.

Here's the full code
http://pastebin.com/CKFQyDmn

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you got something like this?
Checkbutton( self.frame2, text = "Bold", variable = self.boldOn, command = self.changeFont )

You will need something as the command property for your checkbutton so when it changes a certain piece of code is executed.

for reference check here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm